# SSMTP to forward root@localhost mail

Tags: linux, centos, email

I would like to forward mail that gets sent root@localhost on multiple servers to our company admin account (e-mail is hosted on gmail)

I have installed ssmtp on centos 5.5 via yum and configured it. i've also changed the last line in /etc/aliases to reflect where mail to root should go to.

I've then tried sending mail to root - this gets delivered without a problem (mail -v root)
I've also tried sending mail to root@localhost - this is not delivered to the specified gmail account.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `ssmtp` does not read `~/.forward`. Here is a quote from the `ssmtp` manpage.

> It does not do aliasing, which must be done either in the user agent
>   or on the mailhub. Nor does it honor .forwards, which have to be done
>   on the recieving host.  It especially does not deliver to pipelines.

Answer (score 4):

This is a an old post. However, this may useful to some one else.

Based on this link https://theblackdragon.wordpress.com/2011/06/07/ssmtp-and-aliasing-the-to-address/

- Ensure mailx is installed on your system
  ( try   `mailx -?` )
- Edit /etc/mail.rc like this:

  `alias root root<root@myremoteaddress.be>`

Now, mails to root@localhost will be sent to root@myremoteaddress.be
You can add other addresses too, not just root.

Answer (score -1):

Have you configured and enabled *From rewriting*? `locahost` is not a valid domain.

See [this post](http://www.scottro.net/qnd/qnd-ssmtp.html).